# Exemple of real-life non-linear correlation in time series?

Tags: time-series, correlation, random-variable, independence

I am looking for a dataset of 'real-life' time series that exhibits non-comonotonic / non-countermonotonic dependence.

I am not looking for the textbook X^2 correlation, but interesting yet real non-linear association between variables.

Comment: Did you take a look at the UCR Time Series Classification Archive? http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/time_series_data/

Comment: I had a quick look indeed. Not had time to run an analysis on the whole batch yet...

Answer (score 6):

The predator-prey relationship is also a standard textbook example of a real-life, non-linear, lagged relationship between predator and prey population in a closed environment (see [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations)).  As you can see, the predator and prey time series exhibit correlations, and their relationship is highly non-linear:

[image]

[Predator Prey Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equations)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, indeed. Have you also examples of _non-lagged_ non-linear correlations?

Comment: Generally, I think lags are inevitable in real world examples, as correlations often have causal interpretations, which introduces a lag at some timescale.  However, you can think of two time series -- a sine wave and cosine wave -- as an example of a non-linear relationship between two time series, and work backwards to see what physical processes might exhibit such behaviour.  (Example: temperature during the day and time of day, etc.)